# HQL with new object

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Hello I have a HQL query like below in my DAO class.

```
String queryString1 = "select new com.apple.ist.cm.ruleadmin.model.SearchQuestionnaire(qc.questionCategoryID,qc.questionCategoryName, qn.questionReferenceString, qn.question,qao.answerOptionGroupID,answerOptionGroup,answerStringValue) " +" from Questionnaire qn,QuestionCategory qc,QuestionAnswerOption qao,AnswerOptionGroup aog,AnswerString ans "+"where qn.questionCategoryID = qc.questionCategoryID and qn.questionID=qao.questionID and qao.answerOptionGroupID=aog.answerOptionGroupID and qao.answerStringID=ans.answerStringID";

SearchQuestionnaire quest = null;
query1 = (List<SearchQuestionnaire>) hibernateTemplate.find(queryString1);
```

and I have all the models mapped to the 5 tables:

- AnswerOptionGroup.java
- AnswerString.java
- QuestionAnswerOption.java
- QuestionCategory.java
- QuestionCategory.java.

And SearchQuestionnaire.java is a dummy pojo to pass with query having getters setters for all the selected columns from the above query.

```
public class SearchQuestionnaire {

private long questionCategoryID;
private String questionCategoryName;
private String questionReferenceString;
private long questionCategory;
private String question;
private long answerOptionGroupID;
private String answerOptionGroup;
private String answerStringValue;

public SearchQuestionnaire(){

}
public SearchQuestionnaire(long answerOptionGroupID,String answerOptionGroup){
    this.questionCategoryID = questionCategoryID;
    this.questionCategoryName = questionCategoryName;
    this.questionReferenceString = questionReferenceString;
    this.question = question;
    this.answerOptionGroupID = answerOptionGroupID;
    this.answerOptionGroup = answerOptionGroup;
    this.answerStringValue = answerStringValue;     
}
```

........ all the getters and setters
    }

Here with the above I am getting below error:

```
20:05:50,561 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
20:05:50,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:195)
20:05:50,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:137)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:111)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:862)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1956)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1825)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1394)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:553)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:251)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:134)
20:05:50,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1650)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:914)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
20:05:50,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904)
20:05:50,565 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.apple.ist.cm.ruleadmin.dao.QuestionnaireDAOImpl.listQuestionnaire(QuestionnaireDAOImpl.java:300)
20:05:50,565 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.apple.ist.cm.ruleadmin.controllers.QuestionnaireController.listQuestionnaire(QuestionnaireController.java:121)
20:05:50,565 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
20:05:50,565 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
20:05:50,565 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
20:05:50,565 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
20:05:50,565 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
20:05:50,565 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
20:05:50,565 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
20:05:50,565 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
20:05:50,566 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
20:05:50,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

But if i tried with the below query in DAO it works fine

```
String queryString1 = "select new com.apple.ist.cm.ruleadmin.model.SearchQuestionnaire(qc.questionCategoryID,qc.questionCategoryName,qn.questionReferenceString, question)" 
            +" from Questionnaire qn,QuestionCategory qc where qn.questionCategoryID = qc.questionCategoryID";
```

Please help me in resolving the "NullPointerException".

Comment: Your question was not readable, so I edited it for you. But you still have 8 questions you asked without any accepted answer. Follow the rules, or no-one will help you. And try to take some time formatting your code and your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that the second query works, because the arguments of the constructor that the query calls don't match with any of the constructors of SearchQuestionnaire. Make sure that the query uses the same number and the same type of arguments as one of the constructors of the class.

BTW, the second constructor of SearchQuestionnaire is broken. It takes two arguments and initializes most of the attributes with themselves.

BTW, the design of your entities seems questionable, because you shouldn't have to do joins on IDs yourself. Instead, you should have associations between entities and join on these associations. For example, the Question entity shouldn't have a category ID. It should have a ManyToOne association with a QuestionCategory.

Comment: I got the solution for my problem by changing the query as below:

Comment: String queryString1 = "select new com.apple.ist.cm.ruleadmin.model.SearchQuestionnaire(qc.questionCategoryID,qc.questionCategoryName, qn.questionReferenceString, qn.question, qao.answerOptionGroupID, aog.answerOptionGroup, ans.answerStringValue) " +
      "from Questionnaire qn,QuestionCategory qc,QuestionAnswerOption qao,AnswerOptionGroup aog,AnswerString ans " +
      "where qn.questionCategoryID = qc.questionCategoryID and qn.questionID=qao.questionID and qao.answerOptionGroupID=aog.answerOptionGroupID and qao.answerStringID=ans.answerStringID or ans.answerStringValue IS NULL";

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **primitive long with the wrapper class Long**  or make sure all the items returned by **your query are not null**.

The reason is that long is a primitive and can not take NULL value. With hibernate it is a best practice to use Wrapper classes for all the nullable fields in your table.

Comment: I ran the same query in SQLDeveloper and it is giving list of results, so the query is not returning null

Comment: In the list of results was there any NULL values?

Comment: Thats why you have to change the type **long to Long** as I told in answer.because **long is a primitive and can not take NULL value**. also don't forget to accept the answer if it is useful :)

Comment: i tried by changing to long to Long. not working and same error. the column i am getting null for few records is "private String answerStringValue".